# Fatal Exception: main unable to start activity android

Tags: java, android

This is my error, when i launch my application, it crashes. I don't understand error mean:

```
02-04 13:45:36.588 7166-7166/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.erik_.tvmanager, PID: 7166
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.erik_.tvmanager/com.example.erik_.tvmanager.MainActivity}: info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.MovieDbException: Failed to read configuration
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.MovieDbException: Failed to read configuration
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:48)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:35)
at com.example.erik_.tvmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: value of parameter 'api_key' can not be empty
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.ApiUrl.addParam(ApiUrl.java:100)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.requestWebPage(TmdbApi.java:57)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:58)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:45)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:40)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbConfig.getConfig(TmdbConfig.java:18)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:44)
at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:35) 
at com.example.erik_.tvmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my gradle. I used a library( compile group: 'info.movito', name: 'themoviedbapi', version:'1.1'), it is based on api.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.erik_.tvmanager"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile group: 'info.movito', name: 'themoviedbapi', version:'1.1'
}
```

and this is my MainActivity, i want set text in my TextView.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi;
import info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbMovies;
import info.movito.themoviedbapi.model.MovieDb;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.prova);

        String apiKey = System.getenv("MyapiKey");
        TmdbApi tmdbApi = new TmdbApi(apiKey);

        TmdbMovies movies = tmdbApi.getMovies();
        MovieDb movie = movies.getMovie(5353, "en");
        textView.setText(movie.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are integrating with some 3rd party API make sure you did proper setup for this, `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: value of parameter 'api_key' can not be empty`.

Comment: make sure `String apiKey = System.getenv("MyapiKey");` does not return empty string

Comment: You need to read documentation of this 3rd party library to know cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: value of parameter 'api_key' can not be empty
```

The problem is following line:

```
TmdbMovies movies = tmdbApi.getMovies();
```

Make sure that `String apiKey` is not empty.

```
String apiKey = System.getenv("MyapiKey");
TmdbApi tmdbApi = new TmdbApi(apiKey);
```

I don't know what `System.getenv("Myapikey");` returns, but I am pretty sure that it is nothing.